# Cascaded ContextMenu in WPF ComboBox

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, vb.net, xaml

I want to create a `ComboBox` that lets users select items the way the Windows XP start menu allows to select programs:

[image]

Is there a way to insert a cascaded `ContextMenu` inside a `ComboBox`?

I tried this but it doesn't work properly:

```
<ComboBox>
        <MenuItem Header="Top Level 1">
            <MenuItem Header="Sub Level" />
            <MenuItem Header="Sub Level" />
        </MenuItem>
        <MenuItem Header="Top Level 2">
            <MenuItem Header="Sub Level" />
            <MenuItem Header="Sub Level" />
        </MenuItem>
</ComboBox>
```

Answer (score 1):

You will want to try somthing like this, The next level must be inside the first level.

```
<Menu Margin="0,0,0,283">
    <MenuItem Header="Top Level 1">
        <MenuItem Header="Sub Level" />
        <MenuItem Header="Sub Level" />
        <MenuItem Header="Top Level 2">
            <MenuItem Header="Sub Level" />
            <MenuItem Header="Sub Level" />
            <MenuItem Header="Top Level 3">
                <MenuItem Header="Sub Level" />
                <MenuItem Header="Sub Level" />
            </MenuItem>
        </MenuItem>
    </MenuItem>
</Menu>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Do you have to use a ComboBox?

Using the `Menu` control will make your MenuItems work easily... so I would use that instead: http://wpftutorial.net/Menus.html

You can always alter the look of it as well. There are some examples here: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/mahesh/menus-in-wpf/

Else, did you try to wrap your menuitems in a  simply?